# Java Map with list value, filter on another list

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, hashmap, java-stream

I have looked on other topics but I cant find the solutions for my problem. I have a map that contains a key = cartID for example C01 and a ArrayList of products. I want to filter this map on another ArrayList that contains productIDs so I can find all the carts that contain these products. I have following code

```
Map<String, List<OrderLineDTO>> allCarts //contains data these are fetched
List<String> cart; //also contains fetched data for example ["Product01", "Product02"]

allCarts.values().stream().filter(list -> list.stream().allMatch(value -> cart.contains(value.getProductId()))).collect(Collectors.toList()); //filter I'm using but not working
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean not working ? On side not i would say to use `Set<String> cart;` instead of `List<String> cart;`

Comment: from OP: "I want to filter this map on another ArrayList that contains productIDs so I can find all the carts that contain these products" -> all products from the cart must match all products from another ArrayList or some products from cart must match some products from another ArrayList?

Comment: Yep, all products. For example carts = {cart1  = [1,2,3], cart2 = [1,3,4]} and cart = {1,2} then it will return cart1 because it containsAll of cart

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find IDs of the carts containing products *only* in the list, this should work:

```java
List<String> cartIds = allCarts
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> 
        e.getValue().stream().allMatch(p -> productIds.contains(p.getProductId())))
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So the only difference is that I used `entrySet()` instead of `values()`.

To find carts, containing at least one product in the list, `.anyMatch` predicate needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns a list of all carts int the list that contain the specified product ids. Included is an `OrderLineDTO` class to fulfill the demo.

```
        Map<String, List<OrderLineDTO>> allCarts = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> cart = new ArrayList<>(); // also contains fetched data for example ["Product01", "Product02"]
        cart.add("ID7");
        cart.add("ID1");
        allCarts.put("cart1", List.of(new OrderLineDTO("ID1"),
                new OrderLineDTO("ID2")));
        allCarts.put("cart2", List.of(new OrderLineDTO("ID3"),
                new OrderLineDTO("ID5")));
        allCarts.put("cart3", List.of(new OrderLineDTO("ID3"),
                new OrderLineDTO("ID4")));
        allCarts.put("cart4", List.of(new OrderLineDTO("ID6"),
                new OrderLineDTO("ID7")));

        List<String> carts = allCarts.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(
                        prod -> cart.contains(prod.getProductId())))
                .map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(carts);
```

Prints

```
[cart1, cart4]
```

```
class OrderLineDTO {
    String id;

    public OrderLineDTO(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use entrySet() and anyMatch:

```
        allCarts.entrySet().stream().filter(p -> cart.stream().anyMatch(prod -> p.getValue().contains(prod.get))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use containsAll to find my answer. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
List<String> carts = allCarts.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(e -> (e.getValue().stream().map(f -> f.getProductId()).collect(Collectors.toList()).containsAll(cart)))
                    .map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Here in StackOverflow, we thank and understand thanking as upvotes, accepted answers (if possible) and then also comments, if you want to say something more :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is more simple, filters if value equal x then returns a list of keys.

```
List<String> result = map.entrySet().stream()
.filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(x))
.map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```